# RecyclerView with contextual action menu flickering

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextual-action-bar

I have created multi select RecyclerView by using this [link](https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview). Now i want to show no. of items selected on action bar and allow user to delete that items. Somehow i manage to display message of no of item selection and delete icon.But,when i select multiple items my action bar is flickering between new context menu and old menu.i dont know why? I found how to create contextual menu from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab)

Here is my code

```
adapter.setSelectionListener(new DragSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDragSelectionChanged(int count) {

            if (count > 0) {
                actionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                actionMode.setTitle(count + " Items Selected");
            }
            if(count==0) {
                actionMode.finish();
                //actionBar.setTitle("Recycler View Multi Select");
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me.